# Firebase and Cordova

Tags: cordova, firebase, web, cloud

can you please help me, right now I'm developing an Android apps using Cordova. I want to give user notification, from where i read the forum, firebase cloud messaging would help me to do that.

I've seen this github https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase, unfortunately I can't understand

can you please give me some basic example to make my apps got notification? Right now I'm making new project only to make notifiacation runs wells, but still no result. Please help me !

Comment: use this plugin for firbase *cordova-plugin-firebase and after adding this u need to login in the firebase site and download the google-services.json file and put it in your root folder and below is the code for the cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function (token) { // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device navigator.notification.alert(token); }, function (error) { navigator.notification.alert(error); });`

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) { // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device console.log(token); }, function (error) { console.error(error); });`

Comment: `window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function (notification) { console.log(notification); }, function (error) { console.error(error); }); if u follow the above instructions and apply these it will work`

Comment: @Madpop hi sir, I dont know what happen but sudednly i can run it well. idk what happen tho, yesterday i run it, and run with many errors, today i run it and already running well, can you help me further? about retrieving the key, i can do that by using object to array, but i dont think that's a good solution, thanks !